# How to declare a matrix or a vector giving its dimensions?

Tags: maxima

Is it possible in Maxima for me to declare a matrix with a given number of rows and of columns without initializing it? The closest thing I found is the function `zeromatrix`. And how to declare vectors like that?

I want to have them declared so I can fill them in loops.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare things in Maxima prior to using them.
For instance, you could create some lists containing the rows, as in

```
for i:1 thru 6 do myrow[i]:makelist(i+j,j,1,5);
```

Then you could construct the matrix with

```
M[i,j]:=myrow[i][j]
```

and

```
genmatrix(M,6,5)
```

Of course, this can be made more precise if you provide more details of what you are trying to do...